# Resize a pic on "ul hover"

Tags: css, animation, hover, html-lists

I ran into a little problem with CSS recently. I a list which I have styled a bit and now would like the *hover effects*. So, when you hover on a list item, the image inside it gets resized, while the rest (text - span) remains same.

```
<ul id="Somename">
    <li>
    <a id="ID1" href="LINK">
        <img alt="Something 1" src="LINK">
        <span>Text</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="ID2" href="LINK">
        <img alt="Something 2" src="LINK">
        <span>Text</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="ID3" href="LINK">
        <img alt="Something 3" src="LINK">
        <span>Text</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I tried to do the animation just like it's done [here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CreativeCSS3AnimationMenus/index3.html), but wasn't able to do it.

The method I tried was

```
#Somename a:hover > img {width: XXpx; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize CSS3's pseudo methods to target other DOM elements during the transition.

Something along these lines should work for you:

## HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">This Link Grows IMG</a>
        <img src="http://www.google.com/homepage/images/google_favicon_64.png" />
        <p>Filler Text</p>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">This Link Grows IMG</a>
        <img src="http://www.google.com/homepage/images/google_favicon_64.png" />
        <p>Filler Text</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li > img {
transform: scale(.5);
transition: transform .25s ease;
}

li:hover > img {
transform: scale(1);
transition: transform .25s ease;

}
```

View Here: http://jsfiddle.net/2bpayv3q/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example styling your html that should get you started. This will scale the image up and rotate it like in the example:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xavtuv4v/2/)

```
/* Give the parent li item a relative position. Hide overflowed content since image will overflow*/
li {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}
li span {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
/* Set an initial size and rotate to be transitioned */
#Somename a > img {
    width: 200px;
    transition: .4s;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
/* Add hover styles to scale and rotate */
#Somename li:hover a > img {
    width: 300px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```